# Converting CBUUID to String in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I am scanning for BlueTooth devices. I want to log them in an array of strings. I want to be able to save them but get the following errors:

```
Could not cast value of type 'CBUUID' (0x1f2760918) to 'NSString' (0x1f26a42d0).

CoreBT[9728:3053605] Could not cast value of type 'CBUUID' (0x1f2760918) to 'NSString' (0x1f26a42d0).
```

I have the following code below. There is no reference to an array as I can't even get it to a string.

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    
    if let peripheralName = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] as? String {
        
        
        print("peripheral Name: \(peripheralName)")

        let uniqueID = (advertisementData["kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs"] as! NSArray).firstObject! as! String 
        // The above line produces an error
        //Removing as! String will work prevent error but still cannot get from "any" to "string"
        
        let x = advertisementData
        print("x: \(x)")
        let y = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs"]
        print("y: \(y)")
        
        print("uniqueID: \(uniqueID)")
        self.UIDCountNumber = UIDCountNumber + 1
        self.UID_Count.text = String(self.UIDCountNumber)//label counting devices
        
        
        self.last_UID.text = uniqueID as? String //Label is not changing
        
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on getting these as strings so I can store them in an array?

Comment: `as! String` is causing the crash, so `as! CBUUID`, then from `CBUUID`  the is a method to transform it into String. But for the rest, please start naming your var with a lowercase (UIDCountNumber, UID_Count, etc.). Avoid force unwrap (using `!`), and avoid using `NSStuff` when there is equivalent in Swift : `NSArray` => `[CBUUID]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
let uniqueID = (advertisementData["kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs"] as! NSArray).firstObject! as! String
```

produces a crash because the UUID is not of `String` type but of completely unrelated `CBUUID` type. You can extract UUID string from `CBUUID` like so

```
guard let uuids = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs"] as? [CBUUID] else { return }
guard let uniqueID = uuids.first?.uuidString else { return }
```

Also, give up force cast operator - `as!`. This is a really bad practice. Use `guard` statements or optional chaining

Comment: Okay, I get "Cannot invoke 'first' with no arguments" for the second guard statement. Am I missing something?

Comment: `first` is a var, not a function, my bad, see updated code

Comment: The documentation says to use constants such as `CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey` but I'm not seeing that. I'm also not seeing `kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs`. What I am seeing is `kCBAdvDataHashedServiceUUIDs`. What are the differences among these and/or where can I find documentation explaining this?

Answer (score 6):

Apple provides an API for getting the string:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbuuid/1518742-uuidstring

```
var uuidString: String { get }
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the Service UUIDs are of type `CBUUID`, so you should cast to `[CBUUID]` instead of `NSArray<String>`. Btw it's a better idea to use the `CB...Key` constants instead of String literals when retrieving values from `advertisementData`.

Once you have a single `CBUUID` instance, you can use `uuidString` to convert it to a `String` and display it on a `UILabel`.

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

    if let peripheralName = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] as? String {

        print("peripheral Name: \(peripheralName)")
        guard let uniqueIDs = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey] as? [CBUUID], let uniqueID = uniqueIDs.first else { return }

        let x = advertisementData
        print("x: \(x)")
        let y = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs"]
        print("y: \(y)")

        print("uniqueID: \(uniqueID)")
        self.UIDCountNumber = UIDCountNumber + 1
        self.UID_Count.text = String(self.UIDCountNumber)//label counting devices


        self.last_UID.text = uniqueID.uuidString

    }
}
```

Unrelated to your issue, but you should also conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for variable names (`uidCountNumber`, `uidCount` and `lastUID`).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will change the naming convention. I am still cleaning up this code.